# Convert time into seconds string issue

Tags: ocaml

I'm reading book **Real World OCaml** and have got error with code from that book. Since, I don't see any activity on book issues in GitHub, I would like to ask you here. Here is the problem cobe:

```
let log_entry maybe_time message =
    let time = match maybe_time with
        | Some x -> x
        | None -> Time.now ()
    in
    Time.to_sec_string time ^ " -- " ^ message
;;
```

And the error is the next one:

```
Error: This expression has type zone:Core.Zone.t -> string but an expression was expected of type string
```

As I understand it is about calling

> Time.to_sec_string time

Comment: As I understand, the problem is that Tmie.to_sec_string time returns function not a string.

Comment: It seems the function is updated and now has an extra argument of `zone:Core.Zone.t`.  You have to apply some time zone data `z` like `TIme.to_sec_string ~zone:z time`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In older version of Core library the `to_sec_string` function had the following interface:

```
(** [to_sec_string t] Same as to_string, but without milliseconds *)
val to_sec_string : t -> string
```

At some point of time they changed its interface and now it is

```
(** Same as [to_string_abs], but without milliseconds *)
val to_sec_string : t -> zone:Zone.t -> string
```

That means, that now this is a function with two parameters. The first one is still a value of type `Time.t`, but the second is a [labeled](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lablexamples.html#sec42) argument of type `Zone.t` that specifies a time zone. A labeled parameter, unlike a regular positional parameter, can be passed to a function at arbitrary position, so that you don't need to remember the order of arguments. A usual invokation will look like this:

```
let s = Time.to_sec_string time ~zone:Time.Zone.local
```

where `Time.Zone.local` is a time zone object, that represents your local time zone. Since it is a labeled parameter, you can also call the function like this:

```
let s = Time.to_sec_string ~zone:Time.Zone.local time
```

Moreover, since both parameters here have different types, OCaml can even guess who is who without using the label, so you can fallback to positional arguments:

```
let s = Time.to_sec_string time Time.Zone.local
```

Finally, most of types in Core has in there interface `to_string` function. So an easier fix would be to use it, instead of `to_sec_string`. It has a little bit different and more verbose format, though:

```
Time.to_string time ^ " -- " ^ message
```

Answer (score 5):

I found discussion about that issue on the [GitHub](https://github.com/stu-art/examples/commit/bb7750474c353cf0907af41d6ca3fae0f830aa17)

The solution is to add:

```
Time.to_sec_string ~zone:Core.Zone.local (time) ^ " -- " ^ message
```

Even though, I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Time.to_sec_string ~zone:Core.Zone.local (time) : returns a string holding the time. That string is then concatenated with -- and message (thx to ^ " -- " ^ message)